# UPDATE on data from the SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

SELECT FROM TABLE 1:

```
SELECT a.region,a.host 
FROM ftpup a
 , ( SELECT info,type,timestamp, max(date) as time FROM ftpup GROUP BY type ) b 
WHERE a.type = b.type AND a.date = b.time AND a.status <> '0' ORDER BY a.`date` DESC
```

RESULT FROM TABLE1:

> region --- host 
> SB ---  H1
>  BS --- H2
>  PT --- H2

TABLE2:

> hostname --- region ---  status
>  H1 --- SB --- 1
>  H2 --- PT --- 0
>  H2 --- BS --- 1

How do `UPDATE TABLE2` in the table for the status field and set it to 2, where `hostname = host` of the first select (RESULT FROM TABLE1) and `region = region` of the first select (RESULT FROM TABLE1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So easy. Just do it like below:

```
UPDATE table2
INNER JOIN (your inner select) AS table1
ON (table2.hostname = table1.host AND table2.region = table1.region)
SET table2.status=2
```

Comment: Very bad answer. Did you try it yourself?